# Passing value from a file to awk script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to pass certain columns from a file to a awk script and 1 to it.The input text file "prac.txt" contains:

```
Shashank 12
Ram 13
Shyam 44
```

the awk script "awEg" contains:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
i=$2
print "val: ",$i+1;
}
```

the command i am firing is:

```
more prac.txt |./awEg
```

I am getting below output:

```
val:  1
val:  1
val:  1
```

Please point out my mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `awk` variables are not called with dollar sign. Hence, use:

```
print "val: ",i+1;
              ^
              no $
```

All together, it yields:

```
$ awk -f awEg.awk prac.txt    # note no need to `more prac.txt`...
val:  13
val:  14
val:  45
```